# Error loading MySQLdb module in PythonAnywhere

Tags: mysql-connector, pythonanywhere

I just converted my SQLITE database to a MySQL database.  It appears that I converted it correctly.  My application no longer works, though.  The traceback is:

Error running WSGI application
2023-04-08 06:55:06,159: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
2023-04-08 06:55:06,159: Did you install mysqlclient?
2023-04-08 06:55:06,159:   File "/var/www/waynemelnick_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 17, in 
2023-04-08 06:55:06,159:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2023-04-08 06:55:06,159:
2023-04-08 06:55:06,160:   File "/home/WayneMelnick/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2023-04-08 06:55:06,160:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2023-04-08 06:55:06,160:
2023-04-08 06:55:06,160:   File "/home/WayneMelnick/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 24, in setup
2023-04-08 06:55:06,160:     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2023-04-08 06:55:06,160:
2023-04-08 06:55:06,160:   File "/home/WayneMelnick/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
2023-04-08 06:55:06,161:     app_config.import_models()
2023-04-08 06:55:06,161:
2023-04-08 06:55:06,161:   File "/home/WayneMelnick/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 269, in import_models
2023-04-08 06:55:06,162:     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
2023-04-08 06:55:06,162:
2023-04-08 06:55:06,162:   File "/home/WayneMelnick/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in 
2023-04-08 06:55:06,162:     from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
2023-04-08 06:55:06,162:
2023-04-08 06:55:06,163:   File "/home/WayneMelnick/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 49, in 
2023-04-08 06:55:06,163:     class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
2023-04-08 06:55:06,163:
2023-04-08 06:55:06,163:   File "/home/WayneMelnick/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 141, in **new**
2023-04-08 06:55:06,163:     new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))
2023-04-08 06:55:06,163:
2023-04-08 06:55:06,163:   File "/home/WayneMelnick/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 369, in add_to_class
2023-04-08 06:55:06,164:     value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
2023-04-08 06:55:06,164:
2023-04-08 06:55:06,164:   File "/home/WayneMelnick/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 231, in contribute_to_class
2023-04-08 06:55:06,164:     self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()
2023-04-08 06:55:06,165:
2023-04-08 06:55:06,165:   File "/home/WayneMelnick/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in **getattr**
2023-04-08 06:55:06,165:     return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
2023-04-08 06:55:06,165:
2023-04-08 06:55:06,166:   File "/home/WayneMelnick/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in **getitem**
2023-04-08 06:55:06,167:     conn = self.create_connection(alias)
2023-04-08 06:55:06,167:
2023-04-08 06:55:06,167:   File "/home/WayneMelnick/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 193, in create_connection
2023-04-08 06:55:06,167:     backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
2023-04-08 06:55:06,168:
2023-04-08 06:55:06,168:   File "/home/WayneMelnick/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
2023-04-08 06:55:06,168:     return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
2023-04-08 06:55:06,168:
2023-04-08 06:55:06,169:   File "/home/WayneMelnick/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in 
2023-04-08 06:55:06,169:     raise ImproperlyConfigured(

I've tried installing mysqlclient but I get a message Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (2.1.0).

I saw in another post on stack overflow that I could use pymysql instead as long as I add
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

to the init.py file.  I got a message ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql' when I attempted this.  pymysql appears to have installed correctly

One thing that I can think of that might be causing the issue is that I have the free version of pythonanywhere.  Is it possible I need to upgrade to a paid version in order to access these libraries?  I haven't seen anything in the documentation stating this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your traceback, it looks like you're using a virtualenv:

```
/home/WayneMelnick/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv
```

However, it looks like you ran the `pip install` command when you were not working in the virtualenv:

```
Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (2.1.0).
```

In order to install something in a virtualenv like the one that you have (inside the `.virtualenvs` directory, so created with `mkvirtualenv`) you need to first activate it for the Bash console that you're using:

```
workon mysite-virtualenv
```

...and then run the `pip install` command.

Comment: That was it!  Thanks.  I'm new at working with a web server - been on my laptop till now.  This seems obvious in retrospect.